# Difference between inbound and outbound sockets in node

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I am writing a function that will make sure a node instance is gracefully shut down.
To do that, I make sure I `unref()` all sockets. This is what I am doing:

```
       function tidyUp(){
          console.log("Closing the server...");
          server.close();

          console.log("Ordering a hotplate shutdown...");
          process.emit( 'hotplateShutdown');

          // This will give time to server.close() to actually work.. 
          setTimeout( function() {
            console.log("Calling unref() for all Sockets and for the Server:");
            wtf.dump();
            var handles = Array.prototype.slice.call( process._getActiveHandles() );
            handles.forEach( ( h, i ) => {
              var name = h.constructor.name;
              if( h.unref && typeof h.unref == 'function' & ( name == 'Socket' || name == 'Server' ) ){

                console.log("Unreffing:", i );
                h.unref();
              }
            });

            console.log("After unreffing:");
            wtf.dump();

            setTimeout( function(){
              console.log("This process should soon close");
              console.log("Here is the event queue keeping it alive:");
              wtf.dump( true );
            }, 1000);

          }, 1000 );
        };
```

I am concerned because the server also sends email, and I want to make absolute sure that any that is being sent is indeed sent.
Basically:

"Give a `Socket` object, how do you tell if it's an INBOUND socket (one receiving connections, as node's HTTP server would open) or an OUTBOUND socket (one open by `nodemailer` to send an email)."

I will want to `unref()` all inbound sockets, and leave the outbound ones in peace, till all email has been sent.

Hints?

Comment: There is no difference. They are all sockets. It is up to you to keep track of which is which.

Comment: I guess one that has as source IP the host's own IP is a socket "generated" locally... right?

Comment: No. Sockets don't have source IP addresses. They have local and remote IP addresses. Accepted aockets are indistinguishable from outbound connected sockets.

Comment: So the only thing I can do *really* is avoid unreffing the ones that have as remote host/port localhost/smtp really... right? (since they are BOUND to be the ones the application is using to send emails...)

Comment: No, it isn't the only thing you can do. You could keep a collection of the inbound sockets, for example.

Comment: How would I do that with express? Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: Have a look at my answer... anything very wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up keeping track of the inbound sockets opened:

```
      var server = http.createServer(app);

        // Keep track of all inbound sockets. They will be
        // unref()ed at cleanup time
        var inboundSockets = {};
        var socketId = 0;
        server.on('connection',function( socket ){
          socket.__id = socketId ++;
          inboundSockets[ socket.__id ] = socket;
          socket.on('close',function(){
            delete inboundSockets[ socket.__id ];
          });
        });

        process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
          console.error( "Error caught: ");
          console.error(err);

          tidyUp();
        })


        process.on('SIGTERM', function(){
          console.log("TERMINATING THIS INSTANCE!");
          tidyUp();
        });


        function tidyUp(){
          console.log("Closing the server...");
          server.close();

         // The next line is important AS IS as it will tell naps that the
          // server is no longer functional
          console.log("THE SERVER HAS STOPPED");

          console.log("Ordering a hotplate shutdown...");
          process.emit( 'hotplateShutdown');

          // This will give time to server.close() to actually work.. 
          setTimeout( function() {
            console.log("Calling unref() for inbound sockets:");
            Object.keys( inboundSockets ).forEach( ( __id ) => {
              var s = inboundSockets[ __id ];
              console.log("Unreffing inbound socket:", s.__id );
              s.unref();
            });
            db.unref();

            console.log("After unreffing:");
            wtf.dump();

            setTimeout( function(){
              console.log("This process should soon close");
              console.log("Here is the event queue keeping it alive:");
              wtf.dump( true );
            }, 5000);

          }, 1000 );
        };
```

Note that I assign an ID to the socket at creation time (there doesn't seem to be a clear universal way to get a unique ID) and then unref them when the server goes down...